# Jquery and Ajax inside ASP.NET How to update div with model

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In my app I am sending post request with string value with Jquery, then in controller, passed string value is used to get some data from API.

Next controller returns a view and model with data from API inside. That data from model I want to put inside values of few textboxes.

The main problem is that I dont know how to refresh that div with model values. When I used post form without jquery and ajax it works but I want to do it asynchronous.

Js script with post request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btn').click(function () {

            var data1 = $('#textBox').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Fill',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'string',
                data: { number:data1 },
                success: function (data) {

                }

            });

        });
    });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Fill(string number)
    {

        CompanyInfo Info = new CompanyInfo();

        //Here some API actions

        return View("Index",Info);
    }
```

Div with model values inside the Index view:

```
<div id="target">

    <h1>Number:</h1>
    <input type="text" value="@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Num)" id="Number" />

    <br />

    <h1>Company name:</h1>
    <input type="text" value="@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.CompanyName)" id="CompanyName" />

    <br />

    <h1>Street Address</h1>
    <input type="text" value="@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.StreetAddress)" id="Address" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point you're not really working with "views and models" in the ASP.NET MVC sense, you're simply working with JavaScript/jQuery to update your DOM.  How you do that depends on the data you have and is done entirely in here:

```
success: function (data) {

}
```

So what's in `data`?

This implies that you have HTML in `data`, perhaps even an entire page:

```
return View("Index",Info);
```

If that's the case, you probably want to select out of `data` the information you want.  Is it *the same* page that you're already showing?  If so then you can just replace the HTML you already have with the HTML from the page.  Perhaps something like this:

```
var newTarget = $('#target', data).html();
$('#target').html(newTarget);
```

That should grab the HTML of the `div id="target"` from `data` and then set it to that same `div` in the current page.

If the HTML in `data` is different from the current page, then you would need to target what you're doing differently of course.  But ultimately it's the same concept.  Be aware that a side-effect of replacing HTML elements in your page with new elements is that any event binding you had on the old elements is lost.

---

Note that this isn't the most efficient way to do this.  Returning *an entire page* when all you need is an updated model includes a lot of overhead that you just end up ignoring anyway.  This would be a good opportunity to look into using WebAPI controllers in your project, where you could return plain objects:

```
return Info;
```

Or even just returning a `JsonResult` from your MVC controller would do the trick:

```
return Json(Info);
```

That way the `data` variable in your client-side code doesn't contain all of this unnecessary HTML, but instead contains *just* the information in the `Info` object.  With that, you can simply update the values of your `input` elements directly.  Perhaps something like this:

```
$('#Number').val(data.Num);
$('#CompanyName').val(data.CompanyName);
$('#Address').val(data.StreetAddress);
```

It's up to you how you want to approach it.  But you definitely have options and can do a good bit of refactoring to simplify things.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer. I used this Json option and everything works. I really appreciate your help and shared knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `success: function(data)` listener inside your AJAX request. Get your `data` and parse it into the div.